# conflicting two magento extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I have two same extension but both are using for a different-different purpose.

Extension A Config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Mageworks_Fee>
        <version>0.1.5</version>
    </Mageworks_Fee>
</modules>
<global>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <fee>
                    <class>fee/sales_quote_address_total_fee</class>
                    <renderer>fee/checkout_totals_fee</renderer>
                    <admin_renderer>fee/adminhtml_sales_order_create_totals_fee</admin_renderer>
                </fee>
            </totals>
        </quote>
        <order_invoice>
            <totals>
                <fee>
                    <class>fee/sales_order_total_invoice_fee</class>
                </fee>
            </totals>
        </order_invoice>
        <order_creditmemo>
            <totals>
                <fee>
                    <class>fee/sales_order_total_creditmemo_fee</class>
                </fee>
            </totals>
        </order_creditmemo>
    </sales>
   </global>
 </config>
```

Extension B Config.xml

```
 <config>
<modules>
    <Mageworks_Insurance>
        <version>0.1.5</version>
    </Mageworks_Insurance>
</modules>
<global>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <insurance>
                    <class>insurance/sales_quote_address_total_insurance</class>
        <before>fee</before>
                    <renderer>insurance/checkout_totals_insurance</renderer>
                    <admin_renderer>insurance/adminhtml_sales_order_create_totals_insurance</admin_renderer>
                </insurance>
            </totals>
        </quote>
        <order_invoice>
            <totals>
                <insurance>
                    <class>insurance/sales_order_total_invoice_insurance</class>
                </insurance>
            </totals>
        </order_invoice>
        <order_creditmemo>
            <totals>
                <insurance>
                    <class>insurance/sales_order_total_creditmemo_insurance</class>
                </insurance>
            </totals>
        </order_creditmemo>
    </sales> 
   </global>
 </config>
```

Both are conflicting in total price , Please help how can i solve this issue.

Comment: Can you explain with a scenario regarding how the price gets affected by both the modules ,how the insurance and fees totals get calculated etc.

Comment: i am using this extenstion http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total , and i made a another copy of this extension , please see the problem in this question ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100747/tax-calculation-is-wrong-in-magento

Comment: When both these modules are active, I have Grand Total calculation errors, specifically, the tax is not being added to the Grand Total as it should be.

Comment: Are you sure that the tax is not added to Grand total only when these modules are enabled.?Also there are several setting's in Magento (System > Configuration > Sales > Tax ) using which we can include tax to the sutotal ,include tax to the product price etc. Please double check your tax display configuration here System > Configuration > Sales > Tax .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same issue which i faced ,Currently you are adding **before** tag only in one extension so remove this line.

```
<before>fee</before>
```

you have to set the **after** and **before** tag in both of the extension.

In Extension A Config.xml file use this

```
<after>subtotal,discount,shipping</after> 
<before>tax,grand_total</before>
```

and in your Extension B Config.xml file use this

```
<after>fee</after> 
<before>tax,grand_total</before>
```

Hope this will help yours

Comment: Thank you so much.. Vishal Sharma

Answer (score 0):

The sort algorithm used by Magento is not stable and can lead to wrong results. You can use this patch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11954867/288568